# Load complex data structures (with relations and inheritance) with Room

Tags: java, android, android-room

**I have a complex entity relation in my project with inheritance and classic relations. I am searching for an elegant way to load data containing automatically the related data, the following sample situation should explain the problem.**

1. Lets assume I have the following example entity relations:
   [image: Example relation of objects to show the problem]
2. Now I can create an classic `@Entity` class for `Cat`, `Dog`, `PetHolder` and `Holder`. Works fine.
3. I can create now for every entity a `@Dao` class which handles loading and saving the data for an entity. So I create `CatDao`, `DogDao`, `PetHolderDao` and `HolderDao`. In each `@Dao` class I ignore the fields who are dependent on another entity: `listHoldPets` in `Holder`, `pet` and `holder` in `PetHolder` and `petHolder` in `Pet`.
   Now e.g. loading all holders containing only the name is very easy with room and works fine. Also saving each object works fine.
4. But now there comes a problem. I want to load all Holders with a list of petHolders. And each petHolder should also contain the Pet. Now the question is how to do that in an ellegant way. The solution Android presented for relations works only for easy relations. So for example I could create a `HolderWithPetHolder` class and a `HolderWithPetHolderDao` for it. With the `@Relation` annotation I could automatically load all `petHolders` for the `holder` into the `HolderWithPetHolder` object. But all the `petHolder` objects in the list would not contain the `Pet` object.

If you have any code example, link or just an idea about this please let me know. Thanks!

Links:

[Android Room Guideline](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html)

[Android Room @Relation reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation)

Comment: Does no answer mean this is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible!

Your database design wasn't 100% clear from your ERD, so I took some liberties wrt the column and table names, but hopefully this makes sense:

```
public class PetHolderWithPet {

    @Embedded
    private PetHolder;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "petId", entityColumn = "id", entity = Pet.class)
    private Pet;

    // add getters and setters
}


public class HolderWithPetHolderWithPet {

    @Embedded
    private HoldereventSession;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "holderId", entity = PetHolder.class)
    private List<PetHolderWithPet> pets;

    // add getters and setters
}


@Dao
public interface PetDao {

    @Query("select * from holder where id = :id")
    @Transaction
    HolderWithPetHolderWithPet loadItAll(long id);
}
```

See this article:
https://medium.com/@jaclync/android-room-with-nested-relationships-803dad19a500